# Find the width of a Div inside a Td cell

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

My html looks something like this. Now I am trying to find the width of the main content and a smaller table's length.

My code keeps saying that both of the lengths are the same even though from the developer tool, I can see that the inner table is very small, so this can't be right.

Can you tell where am I wrong?

```
Code: 

var $sp = $("div[id*='div2']");
$sp.hide();

var w1 = $("div.body-content").first().width();
var p1 = $("div[id*='Panel1']").width();
alert(w1);
alert(p1);
//I get both this alert as same, but p1 is very smal compared to w1
```

HTML

```
    <td id="Body1" valign="top" class="cl-body">
    <div class="body-content">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="Td1">
                        <div id="Panel1">
                            <table class="ptable1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="blank-cell"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>"Something"</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Div2"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top;" id="Td2">
                        <div id="div3">
                            //A v ery big table
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: any CSS? padding and margins can affect you width... jquery `.width()` vs `.outerWidth()` vs `.outerWidth(true)` vs `.innerWidth()` all can return different values of the same element

Comment: No Css is here, which can reflect this thing

Comment: If that is true then there is no issue. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krju4bd9/). They both have different values (214 and 89)